# Reactjs component - looping through json object - not rendering markup

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am trying to loop through this json to render a set of paragraphs -- although when I gain access to the inner loop - the markup doesn't render - its just blank?

I can read the object details with console logs - but rendering markup appears to take no affect - has it lost scope?

the goal here is to render a batch of sentences that are powered by this json so in retrospect.

```
Score for emotional distress and hyperactivity and concentration is close to the average 
Score for behavioural difficulties is slightly raised
Score for peer difficulties and overall stress is very high 

Score for kind and helpful behaviour is very low
```

Json

```
"contents": {
                "1": {
                  "1": {
                    "alert": "green",
                    "values": ["emotional distress", "hyperactivity and concentration"],
                    "label": "close to the average"
                  },
                  "2": {
                    "alert": "yellow",
                    "values": ["behavioural difficulties"],
                    "label": "slightly raised"
                  },
                  "4": {
                    "alert": "red",
                    "values": ["peer difficulties", "overall stress"],
                    "label": "very high"
                  }
                },
                "2": {
                  "4": {
                    "alert": "red",
                    "values": ["kind and helpful behaviour"],
                    "label": "very low"
                  }
                }
              }
```

Component.

```
var YourCurrentStanding = React.createClass({

    createSentence : function(array) {
      if (array.length === 1) {
        return array[0];
      } else if (array.length === 0) {
        return "";
      }
      return array.slice(0, array.length - 1).join(", ") + " and " + array[array.length - 1];
    },

    render: function() {
      var that = this;

      return (
        <div className="component-container">
          {
            Object.keys(this.props.data.contents).map((key, i) => {      

              console.log("key", key);
              console.log("index", i);

              var ordered = this.props.data.contents[key];
              var that = this;

              return (
                <div className="bands" key={i}>
                  {
                    Object.keys(ordered).map(function(key) {
                        console.log(key);          // the name of the current key.
                        console.log(ordered[key]);   // the value of the current key.
                           return (
                            <p className="large-text margin-bottom">Score for {that.createSentence(ordered[key].values)} is <b className={ordered[key].alert+"-text"}>{ordered[key].label}</b></p>
                          ); 
                    })
                  }

                </div>
              )

            })
          }
        </div>
      );
    }
});
```

---

current demo

```js
var data = {
  contents: {
    "1": {
              "1": {
                "alert": "green",
                "values": ["emotional distress", "hyperactivity and concentration"],
                "label": "close to the average"
              },
              "2": {
                "alert": "yellow",
                "values": ["behavioural difficulties"],
                "label": "slightly raised"
              },
              "4": {
                "alert": "red",
                "values": ["peer difficulties", "overall stress"],
                "label": "very high"
              }
            },
            "2": {
              "4": {
                "alert": "red",
                "values": ["kind and helpful behaviour"],
                "label": "very low"
              }
            }
  }
};



var YourCurrentStanding = React.createClass({

createSentence : function(array) {
  if (array.length === 1) {
    return array[0];
  } else if (array.length === 0) {
    return "";
  }
  return array.slice(0, array.length - 1).join(", ") + " and " + array[array.length - 1];
},
   
render: function() {
  var that = this;

  return (
    <div className="component-container">
      {
        Object.keys(data.contents).map((key, i) => {      
      
          console.log("key", key);
          console.log("index", i);
          
          var ordered = data.contents[key];
          var that = this;

          return (
            <div className="bands" key={i}>
              {
                Object.keys(ordered).map(function(k, j) {
                    console.log(k);          // the name of the current key.
                    console.log(ordered[k]);   // the value of the current key.
                       return (
                        <p key={j} className="large-text margin-bottom">Score for {that.createSentence(ordered[k].values)} is <b className={ordered[k].alert+"-text"}>{ordered[k].label}</b></p>
                      ); 
                })
              }

            </div>
          )
          
        })
      }
    </div>
  );
}
});


ReactDOM.render(<YourCurrentStanding />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"/>
```

--

Problem 1 -

in my build -- its rendering different paragraphs but not connective sentences.

[image]

Comment: Refactor your code so that you can log the data you expect to be there. It's a nightmare as it's written to debug.

Comment: -- but I am getting the console logs - showing the data here -- console.log(key);          // the name of the current key.
                        console.log(ordered[key]);   // the value of the current key.

Comment: ^ I can see it creates the two band divs... and then it access the correct items in the contents array - which really needs to be ordered so the highest number at the top.

Comment: Capture your React components construction into a variable and log that.

Comment: I have? -- it stops to render the paragraph tag -- even with dummy data -- I can see the console logs key and ordered[key]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `Object.keys(ordered).map` instead of `Object.keys(ordered).forEach`.

Comment: That had an affect @Oblosys -- its rendered though just 1 row?

Comment: Should produce a `div` with a bunch of `p`s in it. If that ends up on one row it's probably because of styling. You can check the generated structure by using inspect in your browser. (and you probably want to drop the redundant curly braces around the return statement)

Comment: It seems to produce a string of words in this demo here -- in my build its not building a string of connective words - but it is producing multiple paragraphs. @Oblosys

Comment: -- yo @Oblosys you fixed it -- why would it break on the forEach and not on the map?

Comment: you are right -- the demo css is covering markup -- and my data is different to the demo now - and my data is being rendered correctly in my build - I think you fixed the issue - I am just getting fatigued.